# Visual Studio Array or ListBox Data to Excel Range

Tags: vb.net, excel, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying figure out how to programatically write an existing array or ListBox data set from my UserForm into a defined range of cells in Excel.  I am able to write a single value to a single cell, as seen in the code below, but I have multiple arrays that are 3000+ lines long and I can't hard code each one.

```
    Private Sub ExcelSave_click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
  ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExcelSave.Click

    Dim xlsWorkbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlsWorksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xls As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim resourcesFolder = "C:\DiffractionMonitorFiles\"
    Dim fileName = "DataSave MASTER.xlsx"
    Dim NewFileName = SampleNameTextBox.Text & ".xlsx"
    Dim todaysdate As String = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", DateTime.Now)

    'open excel workbook "DataSave MASTER.xlsx"
    xlsWorkbook = xls.Workbooks.Open(resourcesFolder & fileName)
    'open excel worksheet "Sheet1"
    xlsWorksheet = xlsWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    'enter data into specific cells
    xlsWorksheet.Cells(4, 2) = UserNameTextBox.Text
    xlsWorksheet.Cells(5, 2) = todaysdate
    xlsWorksheet.Cells(6, 2) = SampleNameTextBox.Text
    xlsWorksheet.Cells(7, 2) = EntranceUpDown.Value
```

Using this code can write the data to the excel range, but it writes a single value in every cell rather than the corresponding array/listbox value to the proper range cell.

```
           Dim i As Integer
        For i = dblAreas1(0) To dblAreas1.Length
            xlsWorksheet.Range("j17:j3085").Value = dblAreas1(i - 1)
        Next i
```

If anyone would be able to help with this solution I would greatly appreciate it!  I am very new to VB and have learned what I know through searching and forums like this so I'm sure my code is full of quirks, but I'm enjoying the process!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this, you will need to write each value individually. This can be done with a simple loop:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dblAreas1.Length - 1
    xlsWorksheet.Range("J" & (17 + i)).Value = dblAreas1(i)
Next
```

Your syntax was pretty much right on, you were just missing the iteration flow.

Note that I am *assuming* you want to write all the values of your `dblAreas1` array into column `J` starting at row `17`. This being the case, I updated the bounds of your iteration to accommodate this.

Comment: Hmm, I just added the code to my project and upon running it gave me a: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in DiffractionMonitor.exe

Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"

Comment: @JonathanSawn - This loop replaces your `For` loop posted above. Assuming `xlsWorksheet` is a valid Excel sheet, it should work. To be sure do you have the `17 + ` offset in the `Range` evaulation?

Comment: You assumed correct and your code worked great!  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @JonathanSawn - Glad it worked. I caught that immediately after posting my answer so I edited it quickly. You must have seen the original post instead of the revised one. Cheers.